not all arguments converted during string formatting when trying to execute mssql stored procedure from django
My procedure consists of inserting the data into a table in the database from REST API.
p1,p2,p3 are the parameters coming from the user interface
P1,P2,P3 are my stored procedure's parameters.
Here is my code 
def test(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            P1 = request.data["p1"]
            P2 = request.data["p2"]
            P3 = request.data["p3"]
            params = (P1,P2,P3)
            print(params)
            try:
                cursor.execute("{CALL [dbo].[myStoredProcedure] (?,?,?)}",params)
                if cursor.return_value == 1:
                    result_set = cursor.fetchall()
                    print(result_set)
            finally:
                cursor.close()
            return Response({"msg":"post"})
    else:
        return Response({"msg": "get"})

when I add parameters like this: cursor.execute("{CALL [dbo].[myStoredProcedure] (P1,P2,P3)}")"P1","P2","P3" are inserted in the database but not the value of these parameters.
How to solve this problem ?
  File "C:\Users\HP\.virtualenvs\GFA\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\.virtualenvs\GFA\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\HP\.virtualenvs\GFA\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\HP\.virtualenvs\GFA\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\.virtualenvs\GFA\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\projets\quantum\GFA\api\views.py", line 19, in agence_actions
    cursor.execute("{CALL myStoredProcedure (?,?,?)}",params)
  File "C:\Users\HP\.virtualenvs\GFA\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 121, in execute
    with self.debug_sql(sql, params, use_last_executed_query=True):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\contextlib.py", line 158, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\HP\.virtualenvs\GFA\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 139, in debug_sql
    sql = self.db.ops.last_executed_query(self.cursor, sql, params)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\.virtualenvs\GFA\Lib\site-packages\mssql\operations.py", line 424, in last_executed_query
    return sql % params
           ~~~~^~~~~~~~
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting


What is the request.data exactly? What are you trying to insert?

data from post request. There is no problem at this level. My params variable is indeed a tuple

yes, but is the data correct in the request.data? Does request.data['p1'] provides a value, or is the value just P1?

Yes it is correct.

is it possible that your stored procedure uses "p1" as string, instead of the parameter (i.e. [p1])?

Your call has two ? (i.e. (?, ?)), but you pass three items (i.e. (p1, p2, p3))?

error while editing.

I think somehow you are obfuscating a part that is crucial for the error, like the number of parameters (in the previous edit, there are six). Obfuscating is not a problem, but it of course does not help if you are obfuscating the error, and thus it can not be fixed since the code in the question is correct.

when i write cursor.execute("{CALL [dbo].[myStoredProcedure] (P1,P2,P3)}") "P1","P2","P3" are added in the db. It works but i want to insert values of that parameters.

well, then likely it is the stored procedure itself that uses "P1" iso [P1], so you use the string "P1" instead of the *variable [P1].

As all parameters are strings, replace question marks with string format representation %sin your code.
We will therefore obtain:
cursor.execute("{CALL [dbo].[myStoredProcedure] (%s,%s,%s)}",params)

